# Rerunning terraform configuration for AKS cluster forces cluster replacement

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I've used an AKS module to create my cluster: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest

When I'm rerunning the terraform configuration, after any change, in *"plan"* I can see that the cluster will be replaced due to:

`~ location = "westeurope" -> (known after apply)` **# forces replacement**

I've downloaded the module to see how location is defined, it is:

`location = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location`

My resource group didn't change. Just to be sure I've removed it from the state and reimported again, but it didn't help.

My resource group definition is:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "platform-aks" {
name = "platform-aks"
location = "West Europe"
```

*(I've tried writing "westeurope" instead of West Europe, same result).*

In my module parameters, resource group is defined like that:

```
module "aks" {
source = "Azure/aks/azurerm"
version = "4.14.0"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.platform-aks.name
```

Did anyone encounter anything like that, if yes, how did you solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share your module declaration?

Comment: Unfortunately it is too long to paste it here, but it is defined like that: 

``` 
  module "aks" {
  source  = "Azure/aks/azurerm"
  version = "4.14.0"
  resource_group_name              = azurerm_resource_group.platform-aks.name
  # insert the 26 required variables here
}

```

and the rest of the vars are from here: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest?tab=inputs

Comment: the formatting is broken here in the comments :(

Comment: "after any change" What are you changing?

Comment: it can be anything not related to resource group or to the core of the cluster, e.g. agents_min_count                 = 1 change to 2

Comment: What you could optionally do is use `terraform console` to output the value of `azurerm_resource_group.platform-aks.name`. I mean, I don't expect anything special to happen, but at least it might show you what Terraform sees as the value it is passing to the module.

Comment: terraform state show azurerm_resource_group.platform-aks

# azurerm_resource_group.platform-aks:
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "platform-aks" {
    id       = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/platform-aks"
    location = "westeurope"
    name     = "platform-aks"
    tags     = {

        "environment" = "PRD"
    }

    timeouts {}
}

Comment: that's what it shows, so everything is alright...

Comment: what i will try to do after the holidays, is to download the module and reference it in my mian.tf as a local module and inside the module I will try to define the location (hard-coded).

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from using the `data` source to fetch information about the resource group, which is basically a "problem" on the module level. I don't know about Azure, but sometimes I had issues not defining the AWS profile properly and had similar issues only to realize that I had defined a wrong profile. So are you sure `provider "azurerm" {}" block has not been updated in any way?

Comment: Hm, have the tags maybe changed for the resource group? I'm thinking if that had changed, that might be causing the plan to want to recreate stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For now this was a solution:

https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-aks/issues/155

I have downloaded the module and using it as a local module, where I have "hardcoded" the location.

Comment: Sounds like a bug

Comment: For whatever reason that repo doesn't seem to be [very active](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-aks/graphs/contributors).

Comment: Indeed, but sadly I've already created a prod cluster with it and I've got resources there already, so needed to find a way to live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You using a non-standard provider. You shouldn't be using the [aks/azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest) you should be using the **official** [hashicorp/azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest).

That uses a [`azurerm_kubernetes_cluster`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster) that's actually maintained by MS and Hashi corp.

Comment: I know, but this is a ready module for aks. It's published by Azure: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/aks/azurerm/latest

Comment: Yes, but this seems an obvious bug and like I said, it's not getting maintained. So if you want to address this issue, you can wait and hope for that bug to get fixed or you can jump to the official build and use that as that one IS being maintained